# Does pymongo preserve BSON data types similar to mongoexport and mongoimport

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bson

I am trying to move a collection from an old(ver 4.0.4) mongodb instance to a new(5.0.14) one. I tried to do it with `mongoexport --jsonFormat=canonical` but got read timeout in the middle of the run every time.

Then I found that export can be done using `pymongo`, like this

```
c = sourceClient['db']['collec'].find()
sinkClient['db']['collec'].insert_many(c)
```

I have one final worry, does the above code preserve the BSON data-types similar to `mongoexport --jsonFormat=canonical`?

can someone please explain me how the above code works? does it preserve BSON data-types?

Comment: With `mongoexport`, did you try setting [Timeout Options](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#timeout-options) in the connection URI?

Comment: @rickhg12hs there is no timeout option for [mongoexport](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoexport/) when running from `mongosh`

Comment: `mongoexport` is a commandline program.  It will not work if you try to run it within `mongosh`.  `mongoexport` can use `--uri` and a URI can have timeout options as shown in the linked webpage from my first comment.  Whether it will help you or not, I don't know.  If you haven't tried running `mongoexport` from the commandline, start there.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/index.html

Only `symbol` and `undefined` datatypes are not preserved.

symbol will be converted to string. undefined will be converted to null.

FYI: Those two data types are deprecated anyway. xD
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/bson-types/